# DateTimeOffset & UTC & Loal times in MVC4 - jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In database the dates are stored as DateTimeOffSet.
In the views we have to show the dates in local datetimes.

Since in jquery working with UTC  is much easier, we have to render the datetimeoffset as UTC to views and jQuery/javascript should do the job of converting that to local datetimes.

My problem is, I am returning the model to view and not sure how to return the datetimeoffset as UTC to view or can this be done in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been handled in mvc view by using date-time-in as utc attriute.

Answer (score 0):

You should always store the timestamp as UTC in the database.

The offset does not only depend on the location (e.g. timezone), but also on the time of year (summertime). So my offset in the same location is different depending on the time of year.
That is why storing an offset would implicitly be wrong half of the year for most users.

You can of course re-calculate UTC from an offset server-side, but that will never work for all users - because switch to summertime happens on different days in different countries.
The only thing that is alway absolute and comparable is UTC, which is why you should store that and only to conversion to local time locally on the client.

So the best way is to migrate your DB timestamps to UTC once and then work with that.

Comment: nope.. architect has decided to go with datetimeoffset. need a way how to calculate UTC from offset

Comment: That's old thinking and correct only in one way. Yes you should store the universal date so you have a consistent comparable value with any other date worldwide.  The only problem with that was it lost the information about the original local time zone where it was captured. So the key with the new (SQL 2005 and .NET 3.5) DateTimeOffset is simply that it not only stores enough information to calculate UTC, but also keeps the original context (local time). This should totally replace the old DateTime slowly. This is already common in Java and most XML serialization. Just .NET needs to catch-up.